# How to get a link of the thumbnail of a google drive file using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

How to get a link of the thumbnail of a google drive file using google apps script?

The `getThumbnail()` function gives a blob. But I can't create an image with it

```
function createThumbnail(blob){
  if(blob != null){
    var thumbnailFile = thumbnailFolder.createFile(blob);
    return thumbnailFile.getDownloadUrl();
  }
}

var thumbImg = createThumbnail(file.getThumbnail());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getThumbnailLink(fileId) { 
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  return file.thumbnailLink; // this is the value we need to fetch
}

function run() {
  var fileId = "XXX__Replace here the file's id__XXX";
  var urlth = getThumbnailLink(fileId);
  Logger.log('url-> ' + urlth);
};
```

To obtain the thumbnail for a file, you must give the file's id and don't forget "Activate the Advanced Google Services" => In the Editor go to Resources > Advanced Google Services > and check the ON flag for Drive API.

Answer (score 0):

The blob data is the image - if you download it as the filetype you can open it. You can get a link to the thumbnail with [file.thumbnailLink](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files), but note that these links only last for a few hours as they're made when requested by your application.